# Setting up the "Search this Site" functionality in Mysites?

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, search-scope, enterprise-search

I have been able to configure "find people" on the top of the mysites page by setting it to people search results of the enterprise search center in "Setup MySites" settings from CA.

However I cant seem to get the "Search this site" to work.
Correct me if I am wrong but from what I understand this search field would search for content ony within that particular persons MtySite. Atleast I would like to set it up that way.

How do I get it set up?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup the site collection's search settings (Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Search Settings). Enable custom scopes by pointing the site to your search center, and set the dropdown mode to enable those scopes to be used. Additionally, you should also point it to the applicable search results for your search center, so that when users perform a search they're taken to the search center to see the results.

As this is a site collection configuration, you can bulk apply these settings to existing sites/MySites using PowerShell, or set the properties as part of a feature staple to be automatically activated when a new MySite is provisioned.

Comment: Great! That worked. However Im curious on setting it the property as part of a feature staple. Could you elaborate/guide on how would I go about this? Thanks

Comment: There is a thread on here about setting search properties with code: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13579/sp2010-set-site-search-settings-through-code

Comment: Great thread! Guess Ill use it for now. But it looks like I would have to run this periodically say once a week for the first few months of having set up mysites atleast. The stapling of the property into a feature that you mentioned sounds like a great option though. Let em know of any article or blog I can get started on this. Thanks again!

Comment: The properties themselves are the same as those mentioned in the PowerShell script, if you wanted to set them via an event receiver.

Comment: I tried this solution but not worked for me. In MySite site collection's search settings, I put my search center URL in the custom scope box. choose "show scope dropdown", and point the search results page to search center/pages/results.aspx. however, it seems no change on mysite after I click OK. Am i missing something?